# Selenium webdriver connect timeout

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, teamcity

I run Selenium tests on my Teamcity build server. But the tests can't start, with this error message:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote
>   WebDriver 
>       server for URL http://localhost:56064/session timed out after 120 seconds.
>       ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out

Test base class (abbr):

```
public abstract class TestBase<T> where T : IWebDriver, new()
{
    protected IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }


    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
       this.Driver = new T();
    }

    protected void GotoUrl(string url)
    {
        var completeUrl = UrlFactory.Instance.GetTestUrl(url);

        Console.WriteLine("Starting test at " + completeUrl);

        this.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(completeUrl);

    }

}
```

Test class:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
public class Dashboard<T> : TestBase<T> where T : IWebDriver, new()
{
    private const string Url = "RM/Dashboard/dashboard.aspx";

    [Test]
    public void HasCorrectHeading()
    {
        // Arrange         
        this.GotoUrl(Url);

        // Act
        var heading = this.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".pageheaderContainerxboxcontent span.H1"));

        // Assert
        Assert.That(heading, Is.Not.Null);
    }
}
```

The tests run fine on local development machines, what could be wrong?

Visual Studio Solution:

- Web project with no references to Selenium
- Separate UI-tests project with these references:

  - Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium 3.0.0.0
  - ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core 3.0.0.0
  - WebDriver 3.0.0.0
  - WebDriver.Support 3.0.0.0

All referenced by dll:s, not the Nuget feed.

files 'geckodriver.exe' and 'chromedriver.exe' copied to UI-tests projects bin-folder in a post-build event.

Running TeamCity 10 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, when you have to explain exactly what is happening, you stumble over something...

I realized that Firefox on the TeamCity server was pretty old (v 30), so I updated it to the newest version, and suddenly - the tests ran! :-)

Comment: Yes I exactly faced same issue. I updated driver and it worked.

Comment: Ok, but I updated the Firefox browser on my build machine, not the drivers.

Comment: @NiklasRingdahl if you accept the answer, the others will be able to see your solution easier. AFAIK it is absolutely OK to accept your own answer

Comment: @cyberskunk yes, but there is a 2 day "quarantine" on marking your own anwer as correct, and there is 30 minutes left as of now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

After GoToURL() method add below line:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: Thanks, but the GotoUrl method is never called, the TestSetup fails.